# Не работает метод getClass() при указании типа параметризации

Tags: java, классы

Почему такой код не работает?

```
String str = "string";
Class<String> cls = str.getClass();
```

А такой `Class<String> cls = String.class` будет работать.
И отличается ли чем-нибудь `Class` от `Class<?>`?

Comment: _А такой Class<String> cls = String.class будет работать?_ можно поменять одну строку в примере и попробовать

Comment: Будет работать вот так: Class<? extends String> cls = str.getClass();

Comment: и [немного справки](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--)

Comment: @Grundy случайно попал знак вопроса в конец предложения вместо точки, извините, поправил.

Comment: @Werder я в курсе, что такой будер раотать. Но меня интересует, почему не работает при явном указании типа в одном случае и работает в другом? По каким причинам так происходит?

Comment: потому что в справке написано, что реальный результат выполнения _Class<? extends |X|>_

Comment: @Grundy я так понимаю это сделано из-за того, что метод "Returns the runtime class of this Object"?

Comment: @jisecayeyo, ага, думаю стоит подождать тех, кто получше в jave, они должны объяснить что-чего :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компилятор *не знает*, что в переменной `str` лежит экземпляр класса `String`. С точки зрения компилятора, в этой переменной может лежать любой наследник класса `String`.

В то же время, переменная типа `Class<String>` может содержать только `String.class` или `null` - но не может содержать объект класса-наследника.

Поэтому, присвоить результат выполнения `str.getClass()` переменной типа `Class<String>` и нельзя.

Comment: а он разве не должен был привестись как-нибудь?

Comment: @Grundy разумеется, нет. По той же самой причине, по которой нельзя приводить друг к другу типы массивов.

Comment: а какая-нибудь ко-/контра-вариантность?

Comment: @Grundy в Java любой обобщенный тип можно сделать ко/контра-вариантным, используя синтаксис `? extends X` или `? super X`

Comment: а привести можно было типа так: `(Class<String>)str.getClass()`?

Comment: @Grundy да, но будет ворнинг.

Comment: предупреждение, но не ошибка? и во время исполнения не упадет?

Comment: @Grundy а во время исполнения вся эта типизация вообще исчезает. Обобщенные типы в Java обрабатываются исключительно компилятором.

Comment: @Grundy с другой стороны, если программист "не угадал" с правильным типом - во время исполнения рано или поздно выпадет исключение при попытке выполнения вставленного компилятором преобразования типов.

Comment: А я уж надеялся, что если уж скопилировалось - то в рантайме не упадет :)

Comment: @Grundy кажется, вы перепутали Java и Haskell :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov в Java класс String вроде как final, никаких наследников нет и быть не может (с точки зрения компилятора)

Comment: @PashaPash с точки зрения *другой части компилятора*.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ох уж *эти компиляторы* с диссоциативным расстройством идентичности